# vb.net access to folder denied

Tags: vb.net, forms

I searched everywhere for this error, changing the manifest file of the program to run as administrator but nothing changed, im making a program for myself to get video streaming links where i put the first part of it in the textbox1 and the second part on the textbox2 these get put together and a number for the episode gets added but when i try to save a txt file with all the links i cant save it because the access is denied.

```
Imports System
Imports System.IO
Imports System.Text

Public Class Form1
    Dim l1 As String
    Dim l2 As String
    Dim ep As Integer
    Dim nEp As Integer
    Dim testo As String
    Dim path As String

    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        Label4.Text = "Link:" & vbCrLf
    End Sub

    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        l1 = CStr(TextBox1.Text)
        l2 = CStr(TextBox2.Text)
        nEp = CInt(TextBox3.Text)

        TextBox1.Text = ""
        TextBox2.Text = ""
        TextBox3.Text = ""

        If l1 <> "" And l2 <> "" And IsNumeric(nEp) Then
            If ep <= 9 Then
                For ep = 0 To 9
                    Label4.Text = Label4.Text + l1 & "0" & ep & l2 & vbCrLf
                Next
                If ep > 9 Then
                    For ep = 10 To nEp
                        Label4.Text = Label4.Text + l1 & ep & l2 & vbCrLf
                    Next
                    testo = Label4.Text
                    FolderBrowserDialog1.RootFolder = Environment.SpecialFolder.DesktopDirectory
                    If FolderBrowserDialog1.ShowDialog = Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK Then
                        path = FolderBrowserDialog1.SelectedPath
                    End If
                    File.Create(FolderBrowserDialog1.SelectedPath).Dispose()
                    File.WriteAllText(FolderBrowserDialog1.SelectedPath, testo)
                End If
                End If
        Else
            MsgBox("Inserisci i dati correttamente!")
        End If


    End Sub

End Class
```

Comment: `FolderBrowserDialog1.SelectedPath` is a folder, not a file, correct?

Comment: yes, the error occurs when i try to create the file: File.Create(FolderBrowserDialog1.SelectedPath).Dispose()

Comment: You need to provide a path + file name. Something like: `FolderBrowserDialog1.SelectedPath & "somefile.txt"`.

Comment: Also, there is no need to call `File.Create`. According to [MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.file.writealltext?view=netframework-4.7.2), `WriteAllText` "Creates a new file, write(s) the contents to the file, and then closes the file".

Comment: tried to do it but it doesnt work           Edit: i changed the file creation:                         path = FolderBrowserDialog1.SelectedPath + "\Link.txt" then i added the text to it: File.WriteAllText(path, testo)                    Thank you for the help

Comment: Try using [Path.Combine Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.path.combine). This ensures there is a `\\` between the path and file name.

Comment: `File.Create(FolderBrowserDialog1.SelectedPath).Dispose()` Why are you calling Dispose()?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The big thing I saw was use a **SaveFileDialog** rather than a **FolderBrowserDialog**. But there's a lot more you can clean up, too:

```vb
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim ep As Integer 
    If String.IsNullOrWhitespace(TextBox1.Text) OrElse 
       String.IsNullOrWhitespace(TextBox2.Text) OrElse
       Not Integer.TryParse(TextBox3.Text, ep) Then

        MsgBox("You need to fill the requested inputs!")
        Exit Sub
    End If

    Dim sfd As New SaveFileDialog()
    sfd.InitialDirectory = Environment.SpecialFolder.DesktopDirectory
    If sfd.ShowDialog() <> Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK Then Exit Sub

    Dim names() As String = 
        Enumerable.Range(1, ep).
            Select(Function(e) String.Format("{0}{1:00}{2}{3}", TextBox1.Text, e, TextBox2.Text, vbCrLf)).
            ToArray()
    Dim result As String = String.Join("", names)

    Label4.Text &= result
    File.WriteAllText(sfd.FileName, Label4.Text)

    TextBox1.Text = ""
    TextBox2.Text = ""
    TextBox3.Text = ""
End Sub
```

The meat of the method is this code:

```
Enumerable.Range(1, ep).
    Select(Function(e) String.Format("{0}{1:00}{2}{3}", TextBox1.Text, e, TextBox2.Text, vbCrLf)).
    ToArray()
```

It uses the [`Enumerable.Range()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.range?view=netframework-4.7.2) function to generate a sequence of integers from 1 to the number of episodes parsed earlier into the `ep` variable from `TextBox3`. Then it uses the [`IEnumerable<T>.Select()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.select?view=netframework-4.7.2) function to create a projection of those numbers to the desired strings. `Select()` accepts a [delegate](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/programming-guide/language-features/delegates/) argument, which was supplied here as [lambda expression](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/programming-guide/language-features/procedures/lambda-expressions). This lambda expression uses [`String.Format()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.format?view=netframework-4.7.2) to put each string together. Specifically, the episode number goes in the `{1:00}` placeholder, where the `:00` portion is a [format string](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-numeric-format-strings) to guarantee at least two digits. Then we call `.ToArray()` to roll it all up in a structure that will be compatible with [`String.Join()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa904288.aspx).

Comment: can you explain this part? if possible line by line thx @Joel Coehoorn                
 Dim names() As String = 
        Enumerable.Range(1, ep).
            Select(Function(e) String.Format("{0}{1:00}{2}{3}", TextBox1.Text, e, TextBox2.Text, vbCrLf)).
            ToArray()
    Dim result As String = String.Join("", names)

Comment: @DanieleS. explanation added.

Comment: Thank you! :) @Joel Coehoorn

Answer (score 0):

I Managed to make it work but if i want to use it again without closing the form the button doesnt do anything.

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    l1 = CStr(TextBox1.Text)
    l2 = CStr(TextBox2.Text)
    nEp = CInt(TextBox3.Text)
    nomeFile = CStr(TextBox4.Text)

    If l1 <> "" And l2 <> "" And IsNumeric(nEp) Then
        If nomeFile <> "" Then
            If ep <= 9 Then
                For ep = 0 To 9
                    Label4.Text = Label4.Text + l1 & "0" & ep & l2 & vbCrLf
                Next
                If ep > 9 Then
                    For ep = 10 To nEp
                        Label4.Text = Label4.Text + l1 & ep & l2 & vbCrLf
                    Next
                    testo = Label4.Text
                    If FolderBrowserDialog1.ShowDialog = Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK Then
                        path = FolderBrowserDialog1.SelectedPath + "\" + nomeFile + ".txt"
                    End If
                    File.Create(path).Dispose()
                    File.WriteAllText(path, testo)
                    MsgBox("File created")

                    TextBox1.Text = ""
                    TextBox2.Text = ""
                    TextBox3.Text = ""
                    TextBox4.Text = ""
                    Label4.Text = ""
                End If
            End If
        Else
            MsgBox("File name missing")
        End If
    Else
        MsgBox("You need to fill the requested inputs!")
    End If


End Sub
```

Comment: That's because you never reset the `ep` variable.

Comment: ... and never use the `nEp` variable you had parsed.